# Can JQuery and Javascript be used in the same .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a messaging system that uses ajax that doesn't have to reload when the message is submitted. I have a .js file that uses an onclick to open the form to insert your message and then a differant function to submit the form. Is this not working because I am doing something wrong or because you cant use JQuery and Javascript in the same file.

Here is my code:

```
//I have a button that calls this function with an onclick in my HTML file
function createMessage() {
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.name = "form_input";
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "messages.php";
//I also have a container div in my HTML
container.appendChild(form);

var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
textarea.name = "message_input";
textarea.action = "messages.php"
textarea.method = "POST";
textarea.cols = 84; 
textarea.rows = 16; 
textarea.id = "message_input";
form.appendChild(textarea); 

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "second_picture";
container.appendChild(div);

var submit = document.createElement("button");
submit.innerHTML = 'Send';
submit.id = 'send_message';
submit.name = 'submit';
form.appendChild(submit); 
submit.onclick = submitMessage;
};

function submitMessage() {
$(function() {  
    $("#send_message").click(function() {    
        var message = $("input#message_input").val();    
        var dataString = 'message_input='+ message; 

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "messages.php",  
            data: dataString,  
            success: function() {  
                alert('Ok.');  
            }  
        });  
        return false;  
    });  
});  
};
```

Comment: you can make use of both in one file.

Comment: jQuery **is** javascript, and you can mix jQuery calls and pure Javascript as you wish, provided you are careful about the objects you are working with.

Comment: Please explain what 'not working' means. What is happening? How does that differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't your jQuery and JavaScript, being on the same page it's your code.

**Event Handling Problems**

If you use `onclick` it lets you apply only 1 handler to an event, so it's considered a best practice to use `window.addEventListener` or jquery's event handlers, which let you attach multiple listeners to the same object.

**Event Propagation Problems**

You `return false` in the end of your click event handler you're telling the browser to only do this and not let the event bubble up to any other things that might be listening for events on that element. In this case if you're trying to do 2 **different** things when someone presses the submit button (or whatever) it probably won't work because you've added `return false`. In this case it will probably block a form from submitting for example.

**Incorrect DOMReady Wrapping**

```
function submitMessage() {
    $(function() {
        /* ... */
    });
}
```

You don't need to wrap the inside of this function  with `$(function() {`. Usually you wrap the *entire* file in that and you can still do that here (if it's needed)

Comment: _"and can't be used with others"_ - You can't have multiple _onclick_ on the same element, but _onclick_ can be used side by side with _addEventListener()._

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: You are doing something wrong. `jQuery` is a `Javascript` library, you cannot use `jQuery` without `Javascript`, therefore the two can be used in the same file.

Short story long: Your mistake might be that you try to use `jQuery` functions before `jQuery` is loaded. Or, you might have not initialized a variable. For example I do not see where you initialized the `container` variable. I understand you have a container div, but that's html. We are talking about JS objects now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them in the same file. **jQuery IS Javascript** I would not, though, just because it can be kinda confusing. [Here is a good link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677140/can-regular-javascript-be-mixed-with-jquery)